# systemd MemoryLimit not enforced

Tags: systemd

I am running systemd version 219.
root@EVOvPTX1_RE0-re0:/var/log# systemctl --version
systemd 219
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP -LIBCRYPTSETUP -GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN

I have a service, let's call it foo.service which has the following.

[Service]
MemoryLimit=1G

I have deliberately added code to allocate 1M memory 4096 times which causes
4G memory alloc when a certain event is received. The idea is that after
the process consumes 1G of address space, memory alloc would start failing.
However, this does not seem to be the case. I am able to alloc 4G memory
without any issues. This tells me that the memory limit specified in the
service file is not enforced.

Can anyone let me know what am I missing ?

I looked at the proc file system - file named limits. This shows that the
Max address space is Unlimited, which also confirms that the memory limit
is not getting enforced.

Comment: Are you running this service in user instance of systemd?

Comment: systemd uses cgroups to enforce the limits, so you won't see anything show up via `ulimit` or in proc.

Answer (score 2):

This distinction is that you have allocated memory, but you haven't actually used it.  In the output of `top`, this is the difference between the "VIRT" memory column (allocated) and the "RES" column (actually used).

Try modifying your experiment to assign values to elements of a large array instead of just allocating memory and see if you hit the memory limit that way.

Reference:  [Resident and Virtual memory on Linux: A short example](https://www.darkcoding.net/software/resident-and-virtual-memory-on-linux-a-short-example/)

Comment: Thanks for this example. I do see that allocating 4G without using keeps RES as it. Only after using the memory, I do see RES going to 4G. However, even with "MemoryLimit=1G" in the service file, I am able to make VIRT and RES both reach 4G. I am using systemd 219, which is a little old. Is it that systemd 219 does not support resource management ?